# Why this.props.map is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Pokedex extends Component {
    static defaultProps =
    [
        {id: 4, name: 'Charmander', type: 'fire', base_experience: 62},
        {id: 7, name: 'Squirtle', type: 'water', base_experience: 63},
        {id: 11, name: 'Metapod', type: 'bug', base_experience: 72},
        {id: 12, name: 'Butterfree', type: 'flying', base_experience: 178},
        {id: 25, name: 'Pikachu', type: 'electric', base_experience: 112},
        {id: 39, name: 'Jigglypuff', type: 'normal', base_experience: 95},
        {id: 94, name: 'Gengar', type: 'poison', base_experience: 225},
        {id: 133, name: 'Eevee', type: 'normal', base_experience: 65},
    ];
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="Pokedex">
                <h1>Pokedex</h1>
                {this.props.map((item) => {return <Pokecard {...item} />})};


            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Pokedex;
```

This is my code, and I get the error:

> TypeError: this.props.map is not a function.

Isn't my defaultProps an array? Why would the `map` method not work on it?

Comment: Shout `this.props` not rather be `this.defaultProps`?

Comment: nope. ```defaultProps``` is a special keyword, and I can access the props inside it with ```props```

Answer (score 1):

In React, `props always is an object`.

When you try to assign an array to defaultProps, the array will be `converted to object`. So `this.props.map` will `not be a function`.

You can comment the error line, then add a `{JSON.stringify(this.props)}`

```js
class Pokedex extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = [
    { id: 4, name: 'Charmander', type: 'fire', base_experience: 62 },
    { id: 7, name: 'Squirtle', type: 'water', base_experience: 63 },
    { id: 11, name: 'Metapod', type: 'bug', base_experience: 72 },
    { id: 12, name: 'Butterfree', type: 'flying', base_experience: 178 },
    { id: 25, name: 'Pikachu', type: 'electric', base_experience: 112 },
    { id: 39, name: 'Jigglypuff', type: 'normal', base_experience: 95 },
    { id: 94, name: 'Gengar', type: 'poison', base_experience: 225 },
    { id: 133, name: 'Eevee', type: 'normal', base_experience: 65 }
  ]
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='Pokedex'>
        <h1>Pokedex</h1>
        {/*this.props.map((item) => {return <Pokecard {...item} />})*/}
        {JSON.stringify(this.props)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Pokedex />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 state = { 
    array:[
        {id: 4, name: 'Charmander', type: 'fire', base_experience: 62},
        {id: 7, name: 'Squirtle', type: 'water', base_experience: 63},
        {id: 11, name: 'Metapod', type: 'bug', base_experience: 72},
        {id: 12, name: 'Butterfree', type: 'flying', base_experience: 178},
        {id: 25, name: 'Pikachu', type: 'electric', base_experience: 112},
        {id: 39, name: 'Jigglypuff', type: 'normal', base_experience: 95},
        {id: 94, name: 'Gengar', type: 'poison', base_experience: 225},
        {id: 133, name: 'Eevee', type: 'normal', base_experience: 65},
    ]};
```

and iterate like this

```
{this.state.array.map((item) => {return <Pokecard {...item} />})};
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I was hoping for a method that is using props only, no state.. because I am curious as to why my ```this.props array``` is not recognised as an array

Comment: @AlexDobre are you receiving here from other component?

Answer (score 0):

`this.props` is an Object. You might want to move the items to an array before mapping them to the `Pokecard` Component:

```
render() {
  const pokes = [];
  for (const item in this.props) {
    pokes.push(this.props[item]);
  }
  return (<div className="Pokedex">
    <h1>Pokedex</h1>
    {pokes.map(item => <Pokecard { ...item } />) }
  </div>);
}
```

Comment: Here's a **[Working Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-poke-cards?file=Pokecard.js)** for your ref.